# Firestore Data Modelling ( Users and Problems)

Tags: database, google-cloud-firestore, nosql, data-modeling

I am working on a web app for doing certain problems. The database is **firestore**.

The feature I want to ask is that on a page, **there will show  `{x}/{y}`**,
where *x* is the number of problems the user completed, and *y* is the total number of problems, something like 6/10.

[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tghzY.png)

My doubt is how to design data model to achieve this feature. I already have `users` collection and `problems` collection. My thought is choosing one of them, but feeling none of them is good practice:

A. Adding `user_response` field in each `problem` doc, which means if there are 1000 users, each problem needs to add 1000 users' responses. It is also hard for new users coming.

B. Quite like A but adding `problems_response` into `user` doc.

C. Adding a new collection `repsonses` which has `problem_id`, `user_id` fields.

I am new to NoSQL, thanks for your help.

I added the database structure in the following images:

1. [database-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrddh.png)
2. [database-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xn8Tp.png)
3. [database-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pefPF.png)
4. [database-4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3I2O.png)
5. [database-5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igsx2.png)

Comment: How many documents will exist in the `problems` collection?

Comment: @AlexMamo Currently, there might be 1000 `problem` docs

Comment: What does a single problem contain?

Comment: The data structure is this:  root collection is `skills`. In `skills` collection, we have docs `Emotional Intelligence`, `Empathy` and etc. Each `skill` doc has its subcollection `sets`. In subcollection `sets`, there are `set1`, `set2`, `set3` as docs. In each `setX` doc, there is `problems` subcollection.  In `problems` subcollection, there are `problem1`, `problem2` docs.               Quick sum:   skills[collection] --- skillA[doc] with sets[subcollection] --- set1[doc] with problem[subcollection] --- problem1[doc]

Comment: The field of `problem` doc, there are `order`[number], `asking`[string], `options`[Array], `Answers`[Array], `videoUrl`[string], `posterUrl`[string]

Comment: Instead of describing what your database looks like, please edit your question and add a screenshot of it.

Comment: @AlexMamo Thx for your notice. I just pasted the images in the posted with link. My reputation does not allow me to show original images directly.

Comment: So assuming you have 1000 problems, and a single user solved, for example, only 35, you need to display 35/1000, right?

Comment: Yeah, but slightly different. Like in Leetcode, there are total 2000 more problems. But for each tag, might total 50 problem of a tag. It works the same as mine.

Comment: So you need x/y, where y is the type of a problem, right?

Comment: x is the number of problems solved. y is the total number of problems.

Comment: You can ignore the tag things.

Comment: Do you think it is a good choice to choose C to build a new collection to store the user problem solving history? I think it is more logic than A and B

Comment: Yes, it might work. Give it a try and tell us what's the result.